# Issues while upgrading System.Web.Extensions dll reference from 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-3.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit, migrate, system.web.extensions

I need to migrate a website built on .net framework 3.5 to 4.0 and it should work fine in IE9

The solution got upgraded by the VS's version utility  and the app compiled successfully. We are using Infragistics UltraWebGrid control v11.1 which is giving some script issue when we try to perform scroll or cell edit. The control has got lot of embedded javascript resource files which seems to be not working fine.

I created a poc website of .net framework 4.0 using the same third party dlls and everything works fine. What I can doubt on is the AJAX part. **I tried to consume v4.0 of ajaxcontroltoolkit. But the issue what I am facing is, the toolkit internally  references System.Web.Extensions.dll of version 4.0 and my application has many references to the dll of v3.5**. Adding the reference to v4.0 doesn't replaces the references to v3.5 in the web.config. Finally I manually updated the version info in web.config which has given birth to other errors.

-Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager','asp:UpdatePanel' etc..

-The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Please give me some suggestions to upgrade the dll references successfully.

Thanks,

Vaishali

Comment: I tried the way mentioned in some forums. Fortunately it worked for me too, but how?? No idea. The compile time issues got resolved by downgrading the website build framework to 3.5 and then upgrade back to 4.0. No idea what changed in config but issues went off.

Comment: But!! My sole requirement to solve the script issues on grid's scroll and cell edit is not resolved yet.

Comment: Hey Guys! My problem got resolved. Summary of action: 1.) downgrade website to 3.5, then back to 4.0    2.)Updated my third party controls to compatible version. It Worked!! In step 1.), it actually removed all the references of System.Web.Extensions from my config file and takes v4.0 internally by default.